# calender view with custom background on dates Android

Tags: android

I want to have different color for android calender view for different dates but after searching a lot i did not found a way to change back ground color of dates as i need . can any one   please help me for example see img below.[image]

i want this type of view.

I tried calender class of android .it is opening a calender but i am not able to find way to add colors to that calender view .

my code for that is that below

public class ClaenderViewfragment extends Activity {

```
CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.calenderview);


   initializeCalendar();
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void initializeCalendar() {
        calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // sets whether to show the week number.
        calendar.setShowWeekNumber(false);

        // sets the first day of week according to Calendar.
        // here we set Monday as the first day of the Calendar
        calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);

        //The background color for the selected week.
      calendar.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

  //sets the color for the dates of an unfocused month.
       calendar.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        //sets the color for the separator line between weeks.
       calendar.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        //sets the color for the vertical bar shown at the beginning and at the end of the selected date.
       calendar.setSelectedDateVerticalBar(R.color.transparent);

        //sets the listener to be notified upon selected date change.
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
                       //show the selected date as a toast
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), day + "/" +( month+1)+ "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

http://dizyandroid.blogspot.in/2012/11/custom-calendar-view-using-gridview.html

https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

https://abinashandroid.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/how-to-create-custom-calendar-in-android/

check it ....hope it may help you